# PhoneGap JQuery Mobile Application - Overflow Issue

Tags: jquery, mobile, cordova, overflow

I am developing a PhoneGap application using JQuery Mobile.

I have header & footer NAVBAR's. And In the content section I have this HTML:

```
<div data-role="content"  class="MainContent"  style="overflow:hidden; padding-top: 0px;">
    <ul data-divider-theme="b" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" class="MainMenu">

    </ul>
</div>
```

The  List is dynamically created and works normally fine. However in some cases the overflow:hidden doesn't appear to be working and Header / Footer start moving along with the contents of the main body and become invisible.

Anyone has any idea please?

Comment: Did you fix header and footer?
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" >
by this.

Comment: Here is my Header and Footer:

<div data-theme="d" data-role="header" data-position="fixed" style="padding-bottom: 0px;">

<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

Do I need to change anything?

Comment: no need to use style for header/footer(style="padding-bottom: 0px;" remove this). hope it 'll work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding data-tap-toggle="false" has worked for me. Thanks @NijilNair

Style is needed to remove extra space on the top.